# Стилизация цифр в input range

Tags: html, css

Есть пример стилизации. Как сделать так, чтобы цифра справа была в круге ползунка?

```css
/* Стиль кнопки листалки */
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    max-width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: transparent;
 padding: 0px;
 border: none;
 height: auto;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 7px;
 border:none;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: #e1d7be;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #5b4a38;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 7px;
 border:none;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: #e1d7be;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #5b4a38;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #5b4a38;
    margin-top: -10px;
    color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<form name="nomer_scrollbar">
<input type="range" name="ageInputName" id="ageInputId" min="1" max="$num_pages" oninput="ageOutputId.value = ageInputId.value" value="1" />
    <output name="ageOutputName" id="ageOutputId">1</output>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил `span`, 3 css-правила и скрипт:

```js
function update() {
  var inp = document.getElementById("ageInputId");
  var out = document.getElementById("ageOutputId");
  out.textContent = inp.value;
  out.style.left = (inp.value - inp.min) / (inp.max - inp.min) * 100 + "%";
}

document.getElementById("ageInputId").addEventListener('input', update);
update();
```

```css
form {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 0;
  right: 12px;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

output {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: white;
}

/* Стиль кнопки листалки */
input[type=range] {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    max-width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 background-color: transparent;
 padding: 0px;
 border: none;
 height: auto;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 7px;
 border:none;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: #e1d7be;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #5b4a38;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 7px;
 border:none;
 box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: #e1d7be;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #5b4a38;
    margin-top: -10px;
}

input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: #5b4a38;
    margin-top: -10px;
    color: transparent;
}
input[type=range]::-ms-thumb {
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: goldenrod;
}
```

```html
<form name="nomer_scrollbar">
  <input type="range" name="ageInputName" id="ageInputId" min="1" max="100" value="10" />
  <span><output name="ageOutputName" id="ageOutputId"></output></span>
</form>
```

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы при загрузке страницы стразу работал? Просто если страница не первая, то цифра встает в начало, а надо в круг...

Comment: @АльбертУшаков, просто вызвать функцию.

Comment: По вашему примеру как то не пойму, могли бы Вы подправить свой пример? Чтобы уж другие не спрашивали...

Comment: @АльбертУшаков, готово.